# How do I print a specific item from a for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops

I have this code that's supposed to select 4 random words from a list and put them together to create a password

```
passphr = []

for r in range(4):

    passphr.append(secrets.choice(words_lst))

    print(passphr)
```

This prints out:

```
['cognitive']

['cognitive', 'shakespeare']

['cognitive', 'shakespeare', 'connectors']

['cognitive', 'shakespeare', 'connectors', 'municipal']
```

How do I make it print out only the last line with all the words joined together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and print outside of the loop.

```
passphr = []

for r in range(4):
    passphr.append(secrets.choice(words_lst))

print(''.join(passphr))
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the loop do:

```
passphr = ''.join(passphr)
```

So:

```
passphr = []

for r in range(4):
    passphr.append(secrets.choice(words_lst))

passphr = ''.join(passphr)
print(passphr)
```

```
>>> cognitiveshakespeareconnectorsmunicipal
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `print` inside the loop, you are printing each time `passphr` is appended to. If you only want it to print once, the `print` statement has to be outside of the loop. To print the contents of the list as one word:

```
print (''.join(passphr)
```

> cognitiveshakespeareconnectorsmunicipal